# How to add a scrollViewer in to a stack panel for a text block?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to add an scroll Viewer for a text block who was created from behind c#, text block was added to a stack panel `stackPanel.Children.Add(text block)`. I want to do that in Windows Phone 8.0.

When make something like that:

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();    
ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();    
sv.Content = stackPanel;
```

I receive:

> ExceptionObject = {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}.

One solution to solve that exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollViewer` calculates it's scrollbars based on dimensions of child controls.
If your `TextBlock` has `Height` property set, remove it and ScrollBars should work as expected.

Also you should set:

```
sv.Content = yourTextBlock;
```

Comment: `sv.Content = <TextBlock>` ? That's a compile error. What are you trying to say here?

Comment: don't know the TextBlock instance so i added < TextBlock > so he will understand that needs to add instead of < TextBlock > the instance name.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code (where Content is Grid):

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "hello" };

        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);

        var sv = new ScrollViewer { Content = stackPanel };

        this.Content.Children.Add(sv);
    }
```

I get the desired output:

[image: Manual textbox]

So I tried to reproduce your error. I get the same exception **if TextBlock is null**. So maybe your code which creates the TextBlock has some issues? Here's an example:

```
        TextBlock text = null;

        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Children.Add(text);

        var sv = new ScrollViewer { Content = stackPanel };

        this.Content.Children.Add(sv);
```

Will result in:

[image: Exception]

Comment: I have some text in my textblock, so is not empty,